# How to correctly handle PixelCopy.ERROR_SOURCE_NO_DATA?

Tags: android, blur

On some devices, if activity context is lost due to low memory when application was paused, blur effect on dialog background can not be recreated. In log such situation is related to PixelCopy.ERROR_SOURCE_NO_DATA error in OnPixelCopyFinishedListener. Previously, in that case we just trying to restart pixel copying. When I debugging blur creation, it always successfully recreated. So, for now I added conditional delay, which is activated, when ERROR_SOURCE_NO_DATA is received. But, maybe, this error must be handled in the different way?

```
 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private class PixelCopyTask(
        val window: Window,
        val srcRect: Rect,
        val dstViewWeak: WeakReference<View>,
        val captureViewBitmap: Bitmap,
        val scaleFactor: Float,
        val radius: Int,
        val startTime: Long
) : PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener {
    var wasSourceNoDataError = false
    fun start() {
        try {
            PixelCopy.request(window, srcRect, captureViewBitmap, this, uiHandler)
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            Timber.d("BlurViewBitmapFactory: PixelCopy fail create screen capture")
        }
    }

    override fun onPixelCopyFinished(copyResult: Int) {
        val dst = dstViewWeak.get() ?: return
        checkTime(startTime) { return }
        when (copyResult) {
            PixelCopy.SUCCESS -> setBlurBitmapBackground(captureViewBitmap, dst, scaleFactor, radius, startTime, wasSourceNoDataError)
            PixelCopy.ERROR_SOURCE_NO_DATA -> {
                wasSourceNoDataError = true
                Timber.d("PixelCopy.ERROR_SOURCE_NO_DATA")
                start()
            }
            else -> return
        }
    }
}
```